# Azure AD B2C default URL

Tags: azure-active-directory

After creating an Azure AD B2C Directory and setting up basic sign in and sign up policies and leaving the pages as Default, what would be the Default URL for the sign in page?
Example given Directory Name would be  "**AzureB2CTest18092015.onmicrosoft.com**"

There is a Default page https://login.microsoftonline.com/static/tenant/default/selfAsserted.cshtml
but this has no relationship to a customer directory though.

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a "page" - there is a endpoint URL, the substring ending with "authorize" below, but the sign in process in OpenId Connect involves crafting a URI which contains dynamic elements unique to every request. For example:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/AzureB2CTest18092015.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1_b2csignin&client_id=f3c887c2-30db-40aa-9152-fe1c82f49490&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44316%2f&response_mode=form_post&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3deCM0iMWPJtKXLUHKhtFr-dTOxSXKCN4hb_IpfKvpVumrmx4IkxBx0dfGUrBt0vgaD9-iZWshL6IGAESvnMyPtS9mgcCfcy1XTaCpWW-D-gdRj3xby_1KcOYqutsdq_BEDY6vZotKMyovGxt1ZN18QebjQneEmvn0ixMhdWZXrEMJvbXlmr8THk1rwk-pFmBtT20YLzY1cEfEmOlcQzd2Mw&nonce=635781911983301258.ZjRmYTY1ZjctZTJmNC00ZWRjLWFlYWItZGZmZmI4YWE4OTBmMTY5NWY2OGUtMWY4NS00YThhLThkOGMtMjU0MDlhOTA2OWRi
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. You need to register at least one dummy application in order how you customized branding would look like and to prove authentication.

Answer (score 0):

@SSC365 - I see you were able to create an application and try the policy based flow.

The pages under https://login.microsoftonline.com/static/tenant/default/... are used by default in the signup, signin, profile update flows. You can override them in the page customization section when you create the policies.